# NEO4J Cypher Result Set Display Ordering in Browser

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to arrange the NEO4J Cypher query returned nodes on the browser from left to right.  The nodes are all software applications and they need to be arranged from left to right within the browser by their software application type (such as origination, servicing, default, etc.). I can put either a label on each node or a property in the node specifying the software application type, but I don't know how to specify the order/location in the browser for display.  Perhaps there is another way.  I really prefer not to have a complex solution.  Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to use a custom visualization library, Neo4j browser doesn't support such customization.

Comment: You might want to check out: https://www.yworks.com/neo4j-explorer/